# Linear Search not completing successfully

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops, linear-search

Performing a basic linear search with a loop over an array, and not returning the expected value. Given:

```
students = ["Alex", "Kyle", "Libby", "Monkey Boy"]
```

I'm trying to do a basic linear search to see if the name "Monkey Boy" exists, and return it's index.

```
def linear_search(array, name)
  i = 0
  while i < array.length
    if array[i] == "#{name}"
      return i
    else
      return -1
    end
    i+=1
  end
end

linear_search(students, "Alex") # returns 0
linear_search(students, "Monkey Boy") # returns -1, should return 3
```

Very confused. What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while block is incorrect if look carefully

```
def linear_search(array, name)
 i = 0
 while i < array.length
  if array[i] == "#{name}"
   return i
  else
   return -1
  end
  i+=1
 end
end
```

When you search `linear_search(students, "Alex")`
`"Alex"` is present at array[0], and `array[i] == "#{name}"` is `true` it return i and breaks the loop

When you search `linear_search(students, "Monkey Boy")`
`"Monkey Boy"` is present at array[3], and first time `array[i] == "#{name}"` is `false` i.e `"Alex"` == `"Monkey Boy"` it return -1, i.e. executes else part and **breaks the loop no increment**

If you remove else part out of while the it will work as earlier answer or in more elegant way

```
def linear_search(array, name)
  return array.index(name).nil? ? -1 : array.index(name)
end 

linear_search(students, "Kyle") # 0
linear_search(students, "Monkey Boy") # 3
linear_search(students, "Monkey") # -1
```

Answer (score 1):

`return -1` should be outside the while loop.

```
def linear_search(array, name)
  i = 0
  while i < array.length
    if array[i] == "#{name}"
      return i
    end
    i+=1
  end
  return -1 
end
```

Comment: But isn't that what an "else" clause is for? @liuzxc

Comment: @KyleSnowSchwartz This is true, if you keep the `else` inside the `for loop`, than the `if` statement will run only once, to find that the strings are not equal and so it will run the `else` part and return -1.

Comment: @KyleSnowSchwartz If you're searching for a better way to this. Ruby has so many functions that enable you to do just this with less yet more expressive code.